# Flutter Html parse. Outter html is not correct

Tags: html, flutter, flutter-html

I am parsing Html with html package. I make
c = parse(HtmlContent)
and for example if I will not change it, just make c.outerHtml() and put it to webView or open it in browser it become this error. It happens because tags inside head isn’t closed. But before parse it was closed

[enter image description here][1]
[image]

Comment: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OSMOc.jpg

Comment: If you paste your HTML inside a code block, people might be able to take a look and try to see where the mistake is. It's very difficult to understand from an image

Comment: As an aside, I'm not sure what exactly you're trying to achieve, but I have found the `flutter_html` [package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_html) quite useful for rendering HTML as Flutter Widgets.